# order by max value in sqli

Tags: sql

i want to get result from highest points to low points with Limit and where points greater then 0.

```
"SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE points > 0 ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 0,10"
```

but this query show results in ASC or DSC not the Highest. 
mean I have to values are

```
userID   Points
1        91
2        123
```

it show me the highest 91 not 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your points would appear to be stored as *strings*, not numbers.  In most versions of SQL, you can implicitly convert to a number:

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
WHERE points > 0
ORDER BY points + 0 DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

You can be more explicit as well:

```
ORDER BY CAST(points as int)
```

Note: You have not tagged the question.  Some databases (notably MySQL) require a type name other than `int` (say, `signed`).

Comment: From time to time i've got the impression that you're a mentalist, Gordon.